# in Laravel I GOT AN ERROR The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to when the customer wants to upload an image or logo I want this image to display it in front of him by span element for him to make sure he uploaded the correct image to the system but when I press on upload I got   POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. error

**here is my code in card_view_blade**

```
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <form method="post" id="upload-image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="input-group"  data-type="image">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="image-input">
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                <div class="alert" id="message" style="display: none"></div>
                                <span id="uploaded_image"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**here is the js code**

```
@section('script')

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#upload-image-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let formData = new FormData(this);
            $('#message').hide().html('');

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: `/upload-images`,
                data: formData,
                dataType:'JSON',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log("success-",data);
                    if (data) {
                        this.reset();
                        $('#message').show().html(data.message);
                        $('#message').addClass(data.class_name);
                        $('#uploaded_image').html(data.uploaded_image);
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').hide().html('');
                    }, 3000);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("error-",data);
                    // $('#image-input-error').text(data.responseJSON.errors.file);
                    $('#message').show().html('Something went wrong');
                    $('#message').addClass('danger');
                    $('#uploaded_image').html('');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').hide().html('');
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        });
    })
    </script>
@endsection
```

**route code**

```
Route::post('/upload-images', 'CheckoutController@storeImage' )->name('images.store');
```

Comment: That error page shows that you are indeed using POST, so your blade & js code is irrelevant.

In the console, try `php artisan route:list` - make sure that your post endpoint is listed, and there's nothing above which could be colliding with it

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code perhaps the routes are cached. Try clearing them first and see if the problem is resolved or not with the following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: welcome! this should be a comment!

Comment: Agreed Daniel, I'm a new user so I can not do any comments right now.